# pyspark read delta csv file by date

Tags: pyspark

I have several csv files in a folder. please refer to below screenshot.
[image]

The files with '20221205' are delta files and  are newly uploaded into the folder today.

I want to read these 2 delta csv files only, and do some transformation and then append to existing table.

Every day, i will upload 2 files with current data as suffix, then run the note to handle the files uploaded today only.

Question: how to read only today's file only by pyspark??

How should I load the delta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you call delta is actually a normal csv file with different prefix, not to be confused with [delta data format](https://medium.com/datalex/5-reasons-to-use-delta-lake-format-on-databricks-d9e76cf3e77d).

you can read the prefix using [glob patterns](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/hadoop_glob_patterns.html), simply put the date into the path string and it will read only the files ending with the suffix of the date:

```
spark.read.csv("path/to/folder/*20221205.csv")
```

I recommend however, **if possible**, storing the csv partitioned in your file system. this means each date is in a separate folder.

The file system will be something like:

- folder

  - date=2022-01-01
  - date=2022-01-02
  - ....

then you can simply:

```
spark.read.csv('folder').filter(col('date') == '2022-01-02')
```

the filter on the date will take milliseconds since the data is partitioned, behind the scenes spark knows that csvs with date = X are stored ONLY in date=X folder.

Comment: why it can write to col('date')?? date=2022-01-01 or date=2022-01-02, they are folder name actually, not a column right?

Comment: when you load a folder and Spark detects the sub-folders are all organized in partitions in the format above it adds an inexistent column called date which is the folder (it's not  included in the csvs).

you can also save files in spark this way with df \
.write \
.mode("append") \
.partitionBy("date") \
.parquet("s3://bucket/job_folder/")